# Number of disks in relation to rows and columns in Windows Storage Spaces

Tags: windows-server-2019, storage-spaces

I have been reading through the documentation for Windows Storage Spaces, trying to understand drive provisioning for parity storage spaces. What isn't exactly clear to me is whether the number of columns is a hard limit for the number of disks, or a storage space can be created with a number of drives that is a multiple of the column number.

For example, could a Storage Space set up with single parity and 6 columns, have 12 disks allocated and fully use the capacity of all disks (taking into account usage for parity)?

This article: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/11382.storage-spaces-frequently-asked-questions-faq.aspx#Example_1_A_Two-Column_Simple_Space discusses that the number of disks and columns need to match, however it is unclear whether the number of disks for a parity space can be a multiple of the number of columns.

The accepted answer for the question here: [Mixing disks of different sizes in a Storage Spaces pool](https://serverfault.com/questions/770472/mixing-disks-of-different-sizes-in-a-storage-spaces-pool)
uses multiple disks per column within its answer however that is referring to mirrored storage spaces and I am unsure if that is also true for parity spaces.